# Unable to execute child_process.exec("node child.js")

Tags: node.js

I have two files under a folder with names "app.js" and "child.js". The Node is running on Windows OS.
The app.js file:

```
;(function() {
    var http = require("http"),
    child_process = require("child_process"),
    exec = child_process.exec;

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/plain"});
        exec('node child.js', {env: {number: 1234}}, function(error, stdout, stderror) {
            if(error) throw error;
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderror);
        });
        response.write("Hello world!!!");
        response.end();
    }).listen(8000);
    console.log("The server has started listening to the port: 8000");
})();
```

The child.js file:

```
;(function() {
    var envVar = process.env.envVar;
    console.log("Type of envVar: " + typeof envVar);
    console.log("The value of envVar is: " + parseInt(envVar, 10));
})();
```

I am attempting to execute an external command via "exec" method.
But when I run:

```
node app.js
```

I receive the error:

```
Command failed: 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What wrong am I doing here?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have `node` installed.

Comment: @Alex: I have the node installed. When I write "node" on my command line, i get the REPL.

Comment: you should use fork instead of exec to launch node processes. http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

Comment: @generalhenry: If I write exec("dir \*.\*", function(err, stdout, stderr) {}), it works fine. I am not able to understand why it fails for the situation mentioned above.

Comment: Maybe node is not in the `PATH`, try `exec("path", function(err, stdout, stderr) {})`, and print to the console what's in your path. You can also specifiy the whole path of node, like `c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe child.js`.

Comment: @balazs: The path command is running fine and it's showing me the two files- app.js and child.js. Does it mean the providing absolute path to node is the only option?

Comment: @balazs: Also I think it will throw an error because of the space between Program and Files (C:\Program Files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to `exec` a command, try this:

```
var http = require("http"),
    child_process = require("child_process"),
    exec = child_process.exec;
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"content-type": "text/plain"});
        exec( '"' + process.execPath + '" child.js', {env: {number: 1234}}, function(error, stdout, stderror) {
            if(error) throw error;
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderror);
        });
        response.write("Hello world!!!");
        response.end();
    }).listen(8000);
    console.log("The server has started listening to the port: 8000");
```

the `process.execPath` contains the full path of node.exe, the `"` should be there, because  directory names can contain spaces like `Program files`.

the child process is the same, I just changed `process.env.envVar` to `process.env.number`, because you set that in `exec` options.

```
var envVar = process.env.number;
    console.log("Type of envVar: " + typeof envVar);
    console.log("The value of envVar is: " + parseInt(envVar, 10));
```